# javac not executable for linux 32 bit

Tags: linux, java-7, javac

I just installed the jdk7 on linux 32 bit OS (non rpm). When trying to execute javac command, it just wouldn't work.
To eliminate the environmental path issue, I went into the bin folder directly containing "javac" executable file (it was executable being checked), and simply type javac command, it still won't run with the following feedback:

-bash: ./javac: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or direcry

Anyone knows where the problem is? New to this and thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What `/lib/ld-*` *does* exist?

Comment: didn't understand the question? would you rephrase it? thanks!

Comment: There are files on the filesystem. Some should match the glob I gave. Which ones do?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your responce in time! It would be requiring a dynamic linkage package to be installed. After that the problem would be solved! Thanks a lot for your help and comment though!